# Best way of implementing Oauth user security in ReactJS web developement

Tags: reactjs, security, oauth

We are new to React JS and looking to incorporate existing OAuth authentication process to React framework. 
1. Looking to have any references on best practices
2. Best & secure way to store security key & access key information  or crucial information
 Any references related to this requirement makes great support !

Thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a backend in order to implement Oauth.  Client side frameworks lack the ability to secure data.  So in short you can't implement oauth in React.js without some backend technology.

Comment: Hi Ruby, Thanks for response.  In react, You mean server side storage is only option in general to store access and refresh keys ?  Do we don't have any alternative secured way ?  .

Comment: There is no way to do auth without a backend.  You need a backend, and no there are not alternatives AFAIK.